# Ugly title bar in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

So I'm experimenting with the new material design (looks gorgeous so far). I implemented "Settings" in the action bar and did a workaround in the resources file for it to work:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

Suddenly, a dark Title bar with the App title appeared, the title in black font (I mean the one with TimetableOrganizer, not the one with Vertretungsplan):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUOnu.png]

How can I remove this title bar?

Comment: `I implented a "settings" in the action bar` ?? why would you need a workaround for that?

Comment: `how can I remove this title bar` remove your workaround

Comment: when clicking on the settings, it was giving the null exception error, strangely enough adding the two items `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>` made the error disappear.. probably some inconsistencies with the API's... well but this title bar appeared :/

Comment: instead of searching for a workaround, I suggest you try to fix your NPE. probably a mix-up when using AppCompat, and mistaking getSupportActionBar with getActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

That bar is the ActionBar. Remove it by using

```
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: It should not. You need to find and fix the cause of that NPE.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`